# How can I remove space (margin) around an HTML header?

Tags: html, css, margin

There is always some space above my header. How can I remove it?

My HTML and CSS code is given below.

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>OQ Online Judge</h1>
  <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/base/si" method="post">
    <label for="email1">E-mail : </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email1">
    <label for="password1">Password : </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</header>
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try:

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You're seeing the effects of [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Answer (score 14):

Try margin-top:

```
<header style="margin-top: -20px;">
    ...
```

Edit:

Now I found relative position probably a better choice:

```
<header style="position: relative; top: -20px;">
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

It is good practice when you start creating website to reset all the margins and paddings. So I recommend on start just to simple do:

```
* { margin: 0, padding: 0 }
```

This will make margins and paddings of all elements to be 0, and then you can style them as you wish, because each browser has a different default margin and padding of the elements.

Comment: Be carefull with the use of the * selector. It is very bad for performance. I think you should consider working with a reset css like the one from Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 5):

I solved the space issue by adding a border and removing is by setting a negative margin. Do not know what the underlying problem is though.

```
header {
  border-top: 1px solid gold !important;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, changing `overflow` to `auto`/`hidden` should do the trick too.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>OQ Online Judge</h1>

  <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/base/si" method="post">
    <label for="email1">E-mail :</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email1">
    <label for="password1">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

To prevent unexpected margins and other browser-specific behavior in the future, I'd recommend to include [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) in your stylesheets.

Be aware that you'll have to set the h[1..6] font size and weight to make headings look like headings again after that, and many other things.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the `h1` tag causing the problem. Applying `margin: 0;` should fix the problem.

But you should use a CSS reset for every new project to eliminate browser consistencies and problems like yours. Probably the most famous one is Eric Meyer's: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: you mean margin: 0px;

Comment: Linters even highlight your version: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-units-for-zero-values

Answer (score 1):

This css allowed chrome and firefox to render all other elements on my page normally and remove the margin above my h1 tag. Also, as a page is resized em can work better than px.

```
h1 {
  margin-top: -.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, to cut top margin (as an example):

```
<h2 style="margin:0.3em 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 20em;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>OQ Online Judge</h1>
  <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/base/si" method="post">
    <label for="email1">E-mail : </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email1">
    <label for="password1">Password : </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</header>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.