# How to remove empty space above header?

Tags: css, header, margin, html-heading

I have a very simple header:

```
<header>
    <h1>Hello Everybody</h1>
</header>
```

And I have this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

header {
    background:lightgray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
```

But, I can not position my header on the top of the page. There is some blank space left.

I don't know why is that. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove space (margin) above HTML header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423781/how-can-i-remove-space-margin-above-html-header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `h1` tag you have in your header has a default `.67em` margin. You need to set your `h1` tag to `margin-top: 0px;` in order to get rid of the extra white space.

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

header {
    background:lightgray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `<h1>` still has margins on it.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just as a quick note, if you only want to remove the top margin, do what @amol posted below, `margin-top`.

`margin: 0` is shorthand for `margin: 0 0 0 0`, which combines all margin directions as such: `margin: top right bottom left`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<h1>` tag within the header has a top margin which is pushing your `<header>` tag down.

Answer (score 1):

Heading tags have default margin, you can use following code

```
h1{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why it is a good practice to use a reset css file to eliminate default formatting applied by the browser: http://www.cssreset.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Use bottom margin only, remove top margin

```
h1{
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the `h1` tag comes with a margin, all you have to do is to remove that margin, also some browsers like Google chrome add a default margin so you will also have to remove that margin from the `body` tag.

```
html, body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

h4 {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of your h1 tag. It automatically applies some sort of margin, based on what browser you're using.

To remove the gap use the following within your CSS:

```
h1 {
margin: 0px;
}
```

For the future you want to use Google Chrome or Firefox+Firebug and use the built-in tools to look through all elements within a webpage. It'll save you a lot of time and increases your efficiency.