# Why is there a large gap between sections?

Tags: html, css

I've been creating a page for the last few days and have had this odd gap between the sections I've used. I have them contained in a div named wrapper but even within the div there is about a line's height gap between the top of the div and the start of the section. Further down the page there are also large gaps between the sections.

I can't seem to find a way to change this without messing with the `top-margin` but even then that is quite a 'hacky' way of doing it.

Here's the code to show I really haven't done anything (as far as I can tell) to the attributes.

```
section{
    height:10px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#wrapper{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle if that helps explain what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/L6qeyhsv/

I thought it may be the default values of `section` but that wouldn't explain the gap between the top of `section` at the top of `#wrapper`

Thanks

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: See ["Margin Collapsing" at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove space above header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423781/how-can-i-remove-space-above-header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle,

You needed to remove the margin reset your `<h1>` to 0. A good way to test this is by using developer tools, highlighting the element and seeing what default margins and paddings are applied to the element.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6qeyhsv/5/

Comment: If you want to set your own spaces, set the margin to be larger.  You can use `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-left`, `margin-right`

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset default `<h1>` margin.

```
section h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6qeyhsv/3/

A side note, you can't have multiple `id`s with the same name, they must be unique.

Reference: [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: This is the correct answer, though it may be a bit hard to understand why this helps without a basic understanding of [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).  To those not familiar, it's an important concept.

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple. Thank you. I think I put the ID in when I first started the page with just one section. Must have forgot it was there

Answer (score 2):

If by chance you want to avoid removing the margin from your h1 (which honestly you can and should remove and replace with padding either way), you can use a common clearfix hack to solve this:

```
section:before,
section:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
```

This works by essentially adding "first" and "last" elements which aren't affected by [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).
A longer explanation can be found [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).