# margin: 0; is not setting margin to 0

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design and I'm trying to create a heading for a web page. However, I seem to be getting a bit of empty space above it. I've tried adding a normalizing stylesheet to my document, and setting the margin and padding of the html, body, and header element to 0, but nothing seems to work. How can I delete this white space?

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Jason K</h1>
        <h2>Bum</h2>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.asi.it/files/images/1024X768_02_0.jpg" alt="New York">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://oldweb.lbto.org/images/n891_1024x768.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color:#d7d7e8;
}

/*************************************************
NAV
*************************************************/
header {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  background-color:cyan;
}

/**************************************************
PORTFOLIO PAGE
***************************************************/
#wrapper {
  max-width:1550px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#gallery li {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0% 10%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

a img {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

a p {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}

li a, header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#58585b;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove space above header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423781/how-can-i-remove-space-above-header)

Comment: @KawineshSK Not quite, this one has additional problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a two-part problem, with two alternate solutions.

### Solution 1:

First, the `<h1>` element within your `<header>` element. **[h1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html)** elements have an inherent `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of 16px.

Second, the `float: left;` is causing your header to shift down. Remove `float: left;` from `header {}` and add this to your CSS to have your header sit flush with the top of your page:

```
header h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Example:

```css
header h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

html, body, header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  background-color:#d7d7e8;
}

/*************************************************
NAV
*************************************************/
header {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  background-color:cyan;
}

/**************************************************
PORTFOLIO PAGE
***************************************************/
#wrapper {
  max-width:1550px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#gallery li {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0% 10%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

a img {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

a p {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}

li a, header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#58585b;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#">
    <h1>Jason K</h1>
    <h2>Bum</h2>
  </a>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <ul id="gallery">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.asi.it/files/images/1024X768_02_0.jpg" alt="New York">
          <p>sample sample sample</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://oldweb.lbto.org/images/n891_1024x768.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
          <p>sample sample sample</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

### Solution 2:

Alternatively, you can leave the `float: left;` in and remove the `margin-top` from the **[ul](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul)** element, which also has inherent margins of 16px on the top and bottom. Add this:

```
header h1, #gallery {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

And you will get the same effect as Solution 1.

---

You should **avoid** using a universal selector, because that will cause unintended consequences down the road, not to mention the fact that universal selectors are very slow. There is a small mountain of literature available on the internet about the dangers of using `* {}` for anything, especially as a CSS reset tool.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Use `margin: 0;` and  `padding: 0;` to `*` will solved your issue. Check below your updated code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color:#d7d7e8;
}

/*************************************************
NAV
*************************************************/
header {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  background-color:cyan;
}

/**************************************************
PORTFOLIO PAGE
***************************************************/
#wrapper {
  max-width:1550px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#gallery li {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0% 10%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

a img {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

a p {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}

li a, header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#58585b;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Jason K</h1>
        <h2>Bum</h2>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.asi.it/files/images/1024X768_02_0.jpg" alt="New York">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://oldweb.lbto.org/images/n891_1024x768.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
```

**Second solution:**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Because ul will take margin. Check [Fiddle  here](http://jsfiddle.net/7af72pko/1/)

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  background-color:#d7d7e8;
}

/*************************************************
NAV
*************************************************/
header {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  background-color:cyan;
}

/**************************************************
PORTFOLIO PAGE
***************************************************/
#wrapper {
  max-width:1550px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#gallery li {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0% 10%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

a img {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

a p {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}

li a, header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#58585b;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Jason K</h1>
        <h2>Bum</h2>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.asi.it/files/images/1024X768_02_0.jpg" alt="New York">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://oldweb.lbto.org/images/n891_1024x768.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
```

**Third solution:**

Give clear both to universal selector will solved you issue. like:

```
*{
    clear:both;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7af72pko/2/)

```css
*{
    clear:both;
}


html, body, header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body {
  background-color:#d7d7e8;
}

/*************************************************
NAV
*************************************************/
header {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  background-color:cyan;
}

/**************************************************
PORTFOLIO PAGE
***************************************************/
#wrapper {
  max-width:1550px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#gallery li {
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0% 10%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

a img {
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}

a p {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}

li a, header a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#58585b;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <a href="#">
        <h1>Jason K</h1>
        <h2>Bum</h2>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.asi.it/files/images/1024X768_02_0.jpg" alt="New York">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://oldweb.lbto.org/images/n891_1024x768.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
            <p>sample sample sample</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Universal selectors are dangerous and overly powerful. The problem here is *one element*, not all of them.

Comment: actually `ul` will take margin i updated my answer check new fiddle. If not want to give to give universal selector